# Why is the convex combination of $3$ points in $\Bbb R^2$ a triangle and not a V-like shape?

Tags: convex-analysis, discrete-geometry, convex-hulls

I am new to convexity. I do find it really confusing why the convex combination of $3$ vectors (points) is a triangle and not a V-like shape. With $2$ vectors, it is a segment then why is the case of $3$ vectors it is a triangle or for vectors  greater than $2$ there is a shape i am talking about general case not extreme case where all $3$ vectors are on a line or something like that.

Comment: Please rephrase your question(s).

Comment: What kind of "V like shape"? Is it an infinite area, bounded by two rays sharing an endpoint? Is it two of the three edges of a triangle?

Comment: @mr_e_man by V shape i mean suppose you have 2 vect then the con hull is the line right form 1st vect to 2nd vect and then we add 3rd vect it will create a V shape what i am confused is the difference between convex hull and convex set the definiton of con hull := the set of all con comb of vectors in set S is called the con hull of set S. so if there are 3 vectors in S then the hull should be triangle so a con hull is same as con set i think because every convex comb of vectors in S should lie in Con set of S which might not be true always there may be few vectors that form a convex set in S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a,b,c$ be the three points in our $\mathbb{R}^2$. As you pointed out we can form segments between 2 points by taking the convex combinations of the two points, e.g. $\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b$. And then considering the $\mu b + (1-\mu)c$ gives you your "V". But of course in the convex combination of the three points, e.g. $\alpha_1 a +\alpha_2 b + \alpha_3 c$ you also have the segment $\nu c + (1-\nu) a$ which gives you the "last line of your "V" to complete your triangle".

Comment: The convex hull includes the interior of the triangle, not just the edges.

Comment: Well of course. Then you get your actual area. So for the OP it is important to start realize that by changing all the parameters simultaneously we also end up in the interior of the triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Let your three points be represented by the vectors $a,b,c$.

The convex combination of the points $a$ and $b$ are all the points of the form $xa+yb$ where $x$ and $y$ are non-negative reals which sum to $1$. In other words they are all the points on the line segment between $a$ and $b$.

Similarly you obtain all the points on the other edges of the triangle.

Any point in the interior of the triangle is on a line between two points on edges and so they also are in the convex c0mbination of the three points.